# フリーハンド描画実装に関する canvas と svg の違いは？

Tags: svg, html5-canvas

フリーハンド描画実装に関して、 canvas と svg の違いはありますか？
それぞれ長所と短所があれば知りたいです。

**質問経緯**
Webブラウザで動作するフリーハンド描画ツールを作成しようと思い、色々調べています。
当初はcanvasでしか作成できないと思っていたのですが、 svg で作成している人もいることに気が付きました。

両者を比較した上で何れかを選択したいのですが、その指針となるような情報があれば知りたいと思い質問しました。
フリーハンド描画という機能に関して、canvas でなければできない、あるいは svg でなければできない、ことはありますか？

Comment: 作成されようとしている「フリーハンド描画ツール」に持たせようとしている機能には何がありますか？
フリーハンド描画ツールで作成された画像データを、どのように使おうと思っていますか？
canvasで保存される画像データはJpeg等のラスター形式(突き詰めると、色のついたドットの集まり）、svgは画像の部品(線、円、など）の仕様(”半径5pxの円で、縁は黒、内部は赤、中心座標は(123,46)”というような情報)の集まり。
性質が異なるので、何をしたいのか、何が出来ないと困るのか、といった事情を勘案して選ぶのが良いです。

Comment: 「フリーハンド描画ツール」で作成された内容に対して、後からパス操作したいです。canvasもsvgもパスデータの集まりで何が異なるのだろう？ と思い質問したのですが、canvasはラスター形式ですか？　それともcanvasはパスデータで作成するけれども保存はラスター形式で行われる、という意味ですか？